# Play media file, while it is still downloading (Windows Phone)

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, audio, download, isolatedstorage

I would like to know, if there's a way to play a media-file in Windows Phone, while this file is still being downloaded?

At the current time, I have an application with feature, that allows to download and play media files, when they are fully downloaded.
(I've created this feature, using [article](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=586))

So, in brief, first, the media-file is downloaded from url, then I'm using mediaElement to play it:

```
mediaElement.source = isolatedStorageFileStream;
```

After that, I can use this file via my player UI.

However, I prefer to make this feature better - allow to start playing file, while the download is still in progress. In the end, this should look like that: start downloading file, contemporaneously start decrypting this file, contemporaneously allow to play decrypted part of file. Let's forget about decryption so far(I've already written a method for a downloaded file, it should be slightly changed then), the main problem is how to allow two parallel tasks: downloading and playing.

The first question is: "Does MediaElement only allow to set "source" property to only solid(finally downloaded) files or it can use this Stream, during downloading, as well"?
Because, I've found some info, that:

> "The MediaElement does not supporting streaming at the moment. It
>   loads the *entire* file first before it actually plays it."

, though I'm not sure, that this one refers to Windows Phone, it sounds rather anxiously.

If this cannot be done, what else can I use to work with media-files? I'm not interested in downloading video, let's limit only with mp3 audio files.

Right now, the download process is implemented in this way:

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
webClient.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(webClient_DownloadProgressChanged);
webClient.OpenReadCompleted += new OpenReadCompletedEventHandler(webClient_OpenReadCompleted);
webClient.OpenReadAsync(new Uri(link));
```

Then in OpenReadCompleted the download file stream is set as source of mediaFile.

```
mediaFile.SetSource(isolatedStorageFileStream);
```

After this I can use my media file.

I there a solution for my problem? I'm rather new at Windows Phone threading and streaming and don't know, how to implement such feature.

P.S. Of course, I tried to find a similar question, but failed. If you know one, give me a link, please.

P.P.S. Sorry for my English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only stream it using BackgroundAudioPlayer.

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to read a file that is in use. I don't think is possible.

However:
VideoRecorder works by using filesink and managed to capture, write and display at the same time. would suggest you have a look in that area

How to: Record Video in a Camera Application for Windows Phone
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh394041(v=vs.92).aspx

FileSink
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.filesink(VS.95).aspx